# Migrating to Linuxmint 13 from Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

i am currently using Ubuntu 12.10... Is there any way i can migrate to LinuxMint 13 without formatting/uninstalling Ubuntu ?

Comment: What would you be worried about losing?  Your data should (in very general terms) be in /home/raj and everything else should be replaceable.

Comment: You mean i directly install LinuxMint over Ubuntu ?

Comment: Normally you would back up your home folder, then after installing, you can restore your home folder.  No not 'over' the Ubuntu, but once you have your system installed, you should be able to migrate your dotfiles and ssh keys and other personalized settings into Mint with very little issues.  Do you have a migration plan?  The things you think you will need to keep?  The OS is of little consequence, the data is important.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux Mint installer will detect that your system has Ubuntu installed on it and will offer you the option to install Mint alongside Ubuntu.

When I moved from Ubuntu (12.04) to Mint 14, I simply did a clean install and did not use that option. I assume it requires plenty of unused disc-space, where new partitions can be created.